# jquery conflict with richfaces 4.2.0 and primefaces 3.2

Tags: jquery, richfaces, primefaces, conflict

i' using richfaces 4.2.0 and primefaces 3.2. Everything works ok together (a4j:commandLinks etc.) but when i include

```
a4j:push
```

and any primefaces tag in one page, the a4j stopps working, the a4j commandLinks work only first time the page is loaded.

```
javax.faces.resource/jquery.js.html?conversationContext=m
```

and

```
/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.html?ln=primefaces&conversationContext=m
```

are included

without any p:-tag only

```
javax.faces.resource/jquery.js.html?conversationContext=3g
```

is included.

any help?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [that thread on JBoss community](https://community.jboss.org/message/641745#641745) called "Working towards RichFaces / PrimeFaces compatibility" could help ?